# Oracle find the 1st node and last node in a path, CONNECT BY nocycle

Tags: oracle

I would like to know if there is anyway it return the beginning of the hierarchy and end of hierarchy for the code below

```
 WITH o AS
 (
  SELECT 'A' as obj,
         'C' as link
  FROM   dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C',
         'D'
  FROM   dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D',
         'E'
  FROM   dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X',
         'Y'
  FROM   dual),
apath AS
 (SELECT  obj,
                  link
                  , sys_connect_by_path(obj || '->' || link, ',') pth
                  , connect_by_iscycle as cy
                  , connect_by_isleaf AS lf
                  , level
  FROM   o
  CONNECT BY nocycle obj = PRIOR link)
SELECT *
FROM   apath
where lf = 1
order by pth
```

I would like have the result like

```
Begin_Node, End_Node
A             E
C             E
D             E
X             Y
```

Current code returns

```
D   E   ,A->C,C->D,D->E 0   1   3
D   E   ,C->D,D->E  0   1   2
D   E   ,D->E           0   1   1
X   Y   ,X->Y           0   1   1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` and filter by `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF`:

```sql
WITH o ( obj, link ) AS (
  SELECT 'A', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( obj ) AS begin_node,
       link AS end_node
FROM   o
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY nocycle obj = PRIOR link;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> BEGIN_NODE | END_NODE
> :--------- | :-------
> A          | E       
> C          | E       
> D          | E       
> X          | Y
> ```

If you want all the columns then:

```sql
WITH o ( obj, link ) AS (
  SELECT 'A', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM   dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'E' FROM   dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'Y' FROM   dual
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( obj ) AS begin_node,
       link AS end_node,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( obj || '->' || link, ',' ) AS path,
       CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE as iscycle,
       CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS isleaf,
       level
FROM   o
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY nocycle obj = PRIOR link;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> BEGIN_NODE | END_NODE | PATH            | ISCYCLE | ISLEAF | LEVEL
> :--------- | :------- | :-------------- | ------: | -----: | ----:
> A          | E        | ,A->C,C->D,D->E |       0 |      1 |     3
> C          | E        | ,C->D,D->E      |       0 |      1 |     2
> D          | E        | ,D->E           |       0 |      1 |     1
> X          | Y        | ,X->Y           |       0 |      1 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4be84f152669b1464d9557d7b66c8dcd)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with what `pth` represents, it is simple to extract that info from it:

- line #21: remove leading comma
- lines #27 and #28 return *begin* and *end* nodes

---

```
 <snip>
 18  apath AS
 19   (SELECT  obj,
 20                    link
 21                    , ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(obj || '->' || link, ','), ',') pth
 22                    , connect_by_iscycle as cy
 23                    , connect_by_isleaf AS lf
 24                    , level
 25    FROM   o
 26    CONNECT BY nocycle obj = PRIOR link)
 27  SELECT regexp_substr(pth, '^\w+') begin_node,
 28         regexp_substr(pth, '\w+$') end_node
 29  FROM   apath
 30  where lf = 1
 31  order by pth
 32  /

BEGIN_NODE END_NODE
---------- ----------
A          E
C          E
D          E
X          Y

SQL>
```